# Querying in time intervals throughout history in Splunk

Tags: sql, splunk, splunk-query

I have a query that returns me a count.

I want to get all the counts of a daily/weekly/monthly granularity, spanning a year back.

Currently I can get the counts manually from the presets (last 30 days, last 15 days, etc), or the date range (e.g. Between 20180101 - 20180201), but what I really want is a query that says

"get me a weekly count that spans a year back from today", and it'll return:

```
2018-11-15 to 2018-11-22 : count = 10
2018-11-08 to 2018-11-15 : count = 3
2018-11-01 to 2018-11-08 : count = 6
...
2017-11-15 to 2017-11-22 : count = 11
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.

```
index=foo earliest=-1y | bucket span=1w _time | stats count by _time
```